# How to disable the cut paste option but allow click on phonegap app using css

Tags: ios, cordova, click, copy, paste

I've written my app in Phonegap (for iOS) and have an image that I need the user to be able to "**click-hold**" on and click but stop the "**copy/paste**" option from displaying as it's not required or wanted.

I've seen a lot of posts using the following CSS:

> -webkit-touch-callout: none !important;
>
> -webkit-user-select: none !important;

Which achieves the stopping **copy/paste** prompt, but this also stops the click event, does anyone know how I can achieve this please and leave the click event live?

Regards,

Andy

Comment: to temporarily overcome this issue, I have created a transparent button that sits over the image.  This allows me to have the same click, click-hold, and swipe triggers as the image without the copy/paste showing.

Comment: is above css applicable for MTextBox